# Преобразовать дерево в одномерный массив

Tags: php

Есть древовидная структура выполненная как многомерный массив:

```
$tree = [
    ['id' = 1,'name' = 'Название 1'],
    [
      'id' = 2,
      'name' = 'Название 2',
      'children' = [
          ['id' = 3,'name' = 'Название 3'],
          // и так далее
      ],
    ],
];
```

Как красиво преобразовать этот многомерный массив в одномерный? Например в такой:

```
$arr = [
    0 => ['id' = 1, 'name' = 'Название 1'],
    1 => ['id' = 2, 'name' = 'Название 2'],
    2 => ['id' = 3, 'name' = '-Название 3'],
];
```

Все это хочу сделать чтоб вывести дерево в выпадающий список и видеть в нем структуру подчиненности элементов дерева, например так:

```
<select>
   <option value=1>Название 1</option>
   <option value=2>Название 2</option>
   <option value=3>-Название 3</option>
   <option value=4>--Название 4</option>
   <option value=5>--Название 5</option>
   <option value=6>-Название 6</option>
   <option value=7>--Название 7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть кода, который написан в ответе @splash58, более чем достаточно и для формирования селекта, и для преобразования в массив (и вообще - для обобщения целой группы задач), на всякий случай:

```
$array = tree2array( $tree );
print_r( $array );

function tree2array( $tree, $depth = 0 ) {
    $array = [];
    if( is_array( $tree ) ) {
        foreach( $tree as $node ) {
          array_push
          (
            $array, 
            ['id' => $node['id'], 'name' => $node['name'], 'depth' => $depth]
          );

          if( isset($node['children']) )
            $array = array_merge
            ( 
              $array, 
              tree2array( $node['children'], $depth+1 ) 
            );
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: спасибо :) я бы все равно переписывать не стал, потому что такие спрашиватели у меня вызывают, скажем так, удивление

Answer (score 3):

```
$tree = array (
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'Название 1'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Название 2',
      'children' => array(
          array('id' => 3,'name' => 'Название 3')

      )
   )
);

function make($arr, $pref) {
   global $id;
   foreach($arr as $item) {
       echo 'id=' . $id++ . ' ' . $pref . $item['name']."\n";
       if (isset($item['children'])) make($item['children'], '-'.$pref);
   }
}

$id = 1;
make($tree, '');
```

результат

```
id=1 Название 1
id=2 Название 2
id=3 -Название 3
```

Comment: Ваш код сразу выводит на отображение. Как насчет преобразования в одномерный массив?

Comment: Вы ж просили селект сделать :) Ну замените `echo...`  на засовывание данных в массив, в чём проблема-то?